# Make TextView Bold Italic etc

Tags: java, android

I have one quote application in which I have given option to choose font from assets for text view. its like below

```
text_quotes.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), image));
```

I have another function in which I want give option to make text bold,italic etc. I have tried it like below code

```
text_quotes.setTypeface(null,Typeface.BOLD);
```

but this is changing font to default...How can I make it BOLD etc with same font which applied to text view ?

I am learning android yet...so ignore if My question is very easy. Thanks

Comment: Instead of passing **null**, pass the typeface. Isn't it **obvious**? By passing null, you are re-setting the default font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
textView.setTypeface(textView.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
```

When you are passing null it returns the default Typeface

Comment: Hi ! Thanks its working....I am accepting your answer....when I want remove Bold from text view....textView.setTypeface(textView.getTypeface(), Typeface.NORMAL);  ...I have tried this but its not changing back to normal...any idea what is wrong in this ? Thanks

Comment: In that case pass null instead of getTypeface to check if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Use textView.setTypeface(TypeFace.BOLD);

It works for me.